# Determining the data type of a string value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, types, type-conversion

Ok...this is what I've got. There's an Oracle database table that has a column which is a `VARCHAR` data type. This column, call it 'value', contains strings that represent different values for different things. So some records have a number in this column, others have scientific notation, others dates, other actual characters etc. but they'll all are stored as strings in this 'value' column.

I need to write a view that can query this table and determine what data type is represented by the string in the 'value' column. I know I can do PL/SQL to do this, but I don't have access to create a stored procedure and this needs to be in a view - for other reasons.

Comment: So you have a column `value` with a bunch of random stuff in it?  Is there another column, say, `valueType` which tells you the category is?  Because if not you've just got a column of junk and there's not much you can do with it, except in PL/SQL.

Comment: Also, *why* don't you have the access to do this with PL/SQL?  This appears to be a severely messed-up app, and it is plain stupid to disallow the best tool for sorting it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have an extra column describing the value stored in the `Value` column

```
 Value       VARCHAR2,
 ValueType   VARCHAR2  -- e.g. Age, Name, Money
```

In your view you then use a CASE statement to determine

```
 CASE 
    WHEN ValueType = 'Age' THEN 'integer'
    WHEN ValueType = 'Name' THEN 'string'
    WHEN ValueType = 'Money' THEN 'decimal'
 END As ColumnValueType
```

You can also use Regular expression

Comment: I don't think there is another column. I'm only available to see the one column 'value'.

Comment: I think Oracle 10g and above has Regular expression functions that you can use but that could also get complex

Comment: @EastCarolinaPirate - "I don't think"  Please be certain.  What do mean by "only available"?  Is somebody forbidding you from seeing the full projection of the table?  Or does it really only have one column?